# R-Compare hhmm format data in if loop

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, type-conversion, time-format

I have a dataframe named df, just as below.

```
ID HHmm
1  0840
2  0910
3  1050
4  1210
5  1230
```

I want to add a third column, type, that follows these rules:

```
  for (k in 1 : nrow(df)){
    if(df$HHmm >= 0860 & df$HHmm <= 1060){
      df[k, 'type'] = "r1"
    }else{
      df[k, 'type'] = "c"
    }
  }
```

but I get the warning:

```
In if (df$HHmm >= 0860 & df$HHmm <= 1060) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and I got a undesirable results, just like below.

```
ID HHmm type
1  0840 r1
2  0910 r1
3  1050 r1
4  1210 r1
5  1230 r1
```

The desirable resultes should be like below

```
ID HHmm type
1  0840 c
2  0910 r1
3  1050 r1
4  1210 c
5  1230 c
```

Can anyone spot what's wrong here? How to compare HHmm time format data in if loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the index `k`; e.g. `df$HHmm[k]`.

```
  for (k in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(df$HHmm[k] >= 0860 & df$HHmm[k] <= 1060){
      df[k, 'type'] = "r1"
    }else{
      df[k, 'type'] = "c"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I doubt this will work on its own, since the HHmm column must be character or factor format (note the leading zero, which would not be printed if this were a numeric vector). You probably need `as.numeric(as.character(df$HHmm[k])) >= 0860` and `as.numeric(as.character(df$HHmm[k])) <= 1060`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The type of the column named HHmm is character, only in this way can obtain the results I want. I also had another try, to change the type of column with as.numeric function. It also worked.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to (and should not) use a loop to do this kind of operation in R. It is slower, more verbose and harder to comprehend.

You just want to create a column called `type` with the value "c" and then assign the value "r1" to the subset of the column that meets your condition:

```r
df$type  <- "c"
df$type[df$HHmm >= 0860 & df$HHmm <= 1060]  <- "r1"
df

# Output
#   ID HHmm type
# 1  1  840    c
# 2  2  910   r1
# 3  3 1050   r1
# 4  4 1210    c
# 5  5 1230    c
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion is very useful for me.